# Line equation at a specific point with 45 degree angle on a plane

Tags: matrices, geometry, analytic-geometry

I got a plane with equation: $P(x,y)=\frac{16100+47y}{52}$
A line (parametrized equation) which lies on the plane $P$: $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=t \\ 
y=620 \\ 
z=870
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
And a point which belongs to the line: $O(-5,620,870)$

I need to find an equation of the line that belongs to the specified plane $P$ and crosses specified line at the specified point $O$ making an angle of $45^\text{o}$ with the line.

Here's the respective image from Mathcad: [image]

Comment: There are two such lines. Do you need the equations for both, or is there some additional condition that would determine which of the two $45^\circ$ lines you need?

Comment: Any one of them. Another one should be very easy to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a plane with equation: $P(x,y)=\frac{16100+47y}{52}$

That is not the equation of a plane. It is not really an equation at all. It is the definition of the "$P(x,y)$" function. An equation forces the variables in it into some relationship. If you don't count the function $P$ as a variable, this does no such thing. From the rest of your post, it is evident that the equation of the plane is
$$z = \frac{16100+47y}{52}$$
which forces a relationship between the $y$ and $z$ coordinates of the points on the plane. (Since $x$ does not appear, it can still take on any value. But specifying a value for either $y$ or $z$ forces a value on the other by the equation.)

Solving your problem is most easily done using vector notation. You can rewrite the equation of the plane $P$ as $$-47y + 52z = 16100$$
Or $$\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r = 16100$$
where $\mathbf r = (x,y,z)$ is the position vector, representing points in space as vectors from the origin, and $\mathbf n = (0, -47, 52)$ is a vector. The points of $P$ are exactly those $\mathbf r$ for which the equation holds.

$O = (−5,620,870)$ can be thought of as a vector now. We can verify that it is a point on the plane by calculating
$$\mathbf n \cdot O = (0)(-5) + (-47)(620) + (52)(870) = -29140 + 45240 = 16100$$
You can plug this back into the equation for $P$ as:
$$\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf r = \mathbf n \cdot O$$
and rearrange to get
$$\mathbf n \cdot (\mathbf r - O) = 0$$
as an alternate form of the equation of the plane. Since $\mathbf r$ and $O$ are points on the plane, their difference is a direction along the plane. So this says that the vector $\mathbf n$ is perpendicular to all directions along the plane $P$.
Indeed, $P$ is the unique plane which is perpendicular to $\mathbf n$ and passes through the point $O$.

The line $\ell$ is defined parametrically by the expression
$$O + t\mathbf i$$
where $\mathbf i = (1, 0, 0)$. For every value of $t$, the point $O+t\mathbf i$ lies on the line, and for every point on the line, there is some $t$ for which that point is $O + t\mathbf i$. Note that if $\mathbf r = O+t\mathbf i$, then $\mathbf r - O = t\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf n \cdot (t\mathbf i) = t(\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf i) = t(0) = 0$, which shows that the line does lie in $P$.

To find the $45^\circ$ lines, first find a line in the plane perpendicular to $\ell$. Fortunately the cross product provides what we need. Set $$\mathbf m = \mathbf n \times \mathbf i = (0, 52, 47)$$
Then $\mathbf m$ is perpendicular to both $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf i$:
$$\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf m = (0)(0) + (-47)(52) + (52)(47) = 0\\\mathbf i\cdot \mathbf m = (1)(0) + (0)(52) + (0)(47) = 0$$
So the line $\ell^\perp$ parametrized by $O+t\mathbf m$ lies in the plane $P$ and is perpendicular to $\ell$.

$\mathbf i$ is a unit vector: $\|\mathbf i\| = \sqrt{1^2 + 0^2 +0^2} = 1$. But $\mathbf m$ is not: $\|\mathbf m\| = \sqrt{0^2 + 52^2 + 47^2} = \sqrt{4913} \approx 70.1$. We need unit vectors for the next step, so divide $\mathbf m$ by its length:
$$\mathbf{\hat m} = \frac1{\|\mathbf m\|}\mathbf m = \left(0,\frac{52}{\sqrt{4913}}, \frac{47}{\sqrt{4913}}\right)$$

Finally we can rotate $\mathbf i$ by $45^\circ$ towards $\mathbf{\hat m}$ or towards $-\mathbf{\hat m}$ to get vectors pointing along the two $45^\circ$ lines. For most angles you would use trig for this, but $45^\circ$ is particularly easy:
$$\mathbf u_1 = \frac1{\sqrt 2}\left(\mathbf i + \mathbf{\hat m}\right) = \left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}, \frac{52}{\sqrt{9826}},\frac{47}{\sqrt{9826}}\right)\\
\mathbf u_2 = \frac1{\sqrt 2}\left(\mathbf i - \mathbf{\hat m}\right) = \left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}, -\frac{52}{\sqrt{9826}},-\frac{47}{\sqrt{9826}}\right)$$

The parametric expressions for the two lines are $O + t\mathbf u_1$ and $O + t\mathbf u_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation and solution! At the last step, when you do rotation for 45 deg, isn't it possible just to add (1,0,0) or (-1,0,0) vectors to your m normalized?

Comment: Yes. the $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ just normallizes the $\mathbf u_1,\mathbf u_2$ vectors (makes them unit length). But as far as the parametrizations go, that only changes the value of $t$ needed to get any particular point. When the vectors are unit length, then the $t$ value corresponding to a point is the distance from $O$ to that point. But if that bit of added knowledge isn't helpful to your application, then there is no particular need to make $\mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2$ to be unit length.

Comment: I see. I just didn't fully understand where $$\frac1{\sqrt 2}$$ came from. Now I see that this is the normalization as well.